# spark-shell: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, windows, apache-spark, environment-variables

After I have installed an anaconda package, I can not start the Spark Shell anymore under Windows 7. Whenever I type `spark-shell`, the console answers with `The system cannot find the path specified.` The Spark Shell does not start of course.

I have the following `echo %PATH%`:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramFiles\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Fingerprint Manager Pro\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin; **C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin;**
>   C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin;
>   **C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin;D:\Spark\bin;D:\Hadoop\bin**

And the following `echo %SPARK_HOME%`:

> D:\Spark

And the following `echo %JAVA_HOME%`:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_144

This is my `java -version`:

> java version "1.8.0_144"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

I have already tried to reinstall Java, but without any success. There is a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734210/system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-in-spark-shell), but I don't see any wrong environment variables in my setup. So I have really no idea how to resolve this... Any thoughts?

After some testing I found out that when I `cd` into `$SPARK_HOME$\bin` I can actually execute `spark-shell`. It exits with an error message:

> \Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\java was unexpected at this time.

This error arises when executing the last line `"%~dp0spark-class2.cmd" %CLASS% %*` of `Spark\bin\spark-submit2.cmd`.

**UPDATE 1:**

Changing the `%JAVA_HOME%` from "C:\Program Files..." to "C:\PROGRA~1..." indeed solved this issue in some parts: `spark-shell` now seems to start. However, there are a lot of `Access denied` errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$insta
ntiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1053)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSessio
n.scala:130)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSessio
n.scala:130)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scal
a:129)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(Spar
kSession.scala:938)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(Spar
kSession.scala:938)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:93
8)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:97)
... 47 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: j
ava.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied;
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalo
g.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCa
talog.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(Shared
State.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala
:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessi
onStateBuilder.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSe
ssionStateBuilder.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateB
uilder.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateB
uilder.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStat
eBuilder.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$insta
ntiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1050)
... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOExc
eption: Access is denied
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)

at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala
:191)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(Isolated
ClientLoader.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:3
62)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:2
66)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExterna
lCatalog.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.sc
ala:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.app
ly$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.app
ly(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.app
ly(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalo
g.scala:97)
... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:515)

... 84 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createTempFile(SessionState.
java:818)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:513)

... 84 more
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
import spark.implicits._
       ^

<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
import spark.sql
       ^
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Running `spark-shell` as an administrator works! However, this might be very unsafe and I don't consider it a real solution.

Comment: The space between `Program` and `Files` in `JAVA_HOME` might be the culprit here.

Comment: Whats the best way to solve this? Reinstall Java again? By the way, I also had a space in my java directory when it worked some time ago...

Comment: I'm not sure if that is causing the error but you can try re-installing java to a path without spaces. Something like `C:\Java\`

Comment: You idea was good, however, it is not enough to fix this problem. I updated the question. By the way, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892555/how-do-i-specify-c-program-files-without-a-space-in-it-for-programs-that-cant) is a nice hint how to remove the space.

Comment: I think now you should look to add a `hive-site.xml` and the `winutils` library, if you haven't already.

Comment: Apparently, it seems to work when I start spark-shell as administrator. So there appear to be some right conflicts. I have no idea where and why though.

Comment: Please check this answer stackoverflow.com/a/52831841/2516356

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have set your JAVA_HOME and SBT_HOME correctly, I also add them to the Path variable as well to be on the safe side. To do this easily I could recommend "rapid environment editor", simple and nice tool for editing system variables. This approach made it work for me as I was getting the same problem as you are. An example would be:

JAVA_HOME set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151

SBT_HOME set to C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\