# Error Calling spark from spark shell command on window server 2008

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am installing spark on my  machine- **Window server 2008r2**.
I have followed the below step.

1. Install JDK
2. Add to Environmental Variable
3. Add winutil as Hadoop_Home in Env. Variable
4. Download Spark and configured env variable as SPARK_HOME

**i have not installed scala.**

when i tried to call spark from command line getting below error.

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Please help me how can i fix this. i have admin account on this server, and i set the path in system variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be because of the `\bin` after the `JAVA_HOME` path. Spark has issues with that. Remove the `\bin` after `JAVA_HOME` and run the `spark-shell` command. It should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot adrian, i did like %JAVA_HOME%;%SPARK_HOME%/bin.... but still the same issue. i am doing in system properties. kindly help me if i am doing something wrong

Comment: any suggestion please.

Comment: Are you getting the same error as above? Can you run the spark-shell command from the /spark/bin folder instead of the /spark folder and check?

Comment: i did like this. cd spark/bin then spark-shell but still getting error as the system cannot find the path specified. i have configured all env.variable under system variable, is this the reason, not sure

Comment: This is how my env. variable are :  %JAVA_HOME%;
%SPARK_HOME%\bin. Kindly suggest if i need to do any changes please

Comment: Have you installed **winutils** package? Also, can you refer this link, not sure if you seen this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734210/system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-in-spark-shell