# spark-submit is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to run my first spark program but I am stuck up in this .

I am using enthought canopy for python and set my path variable `%SPARK_HOME%\ , %JAVA_HOME%\,C:\WINDOWS/system32` .
while running spark-submit `ratings-counter.py` in my `canopy` command promt ,it is showing the error of spark-submit is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. 
Anybody can help would be great

Answer (score 3):

In windows 
goto command prompt and type set SPARK_HOME

then home directory would be printed, then type the following command line :

```
%SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-shell
```

If it is coming correctly then your configuration is correct. Through Canopy also you can try.

Further...Look at

- [spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html)
- [spark-trying-to-run-spark-shell-but-get-cmd-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964920/spark-trying-to-run-spark-shell-but-get-cmd-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal)

***Tip for Find existing spark configuration from linux prompt :***

Find location of your existing spark install and spark configuration being used. This is usually in `/etc/spark/conf`

```
readlink -f spark-submit  // windows doesnt have readlink
```

output would be like

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.0-1.cdh5.5.0.p0.27

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.0-1.cdh5.5.0.p0.27/lib/spark/conf -> /etc/spark/conf
```

- Additionally, please go through [this](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-submit.html)
- Update : [how-to-start-a-spark-shell-using-pyspark-in-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665402/how-to-start-a-spark-shell-using-pyspark-in-windows)

Comment: Sir , i did as u said above , spark is running perfectly fine . now how to run an application in enthought canopy . i am doing spark-submit "name of the file" and hitting enter . but it is showing the same error not recognized .

Comment: pls see my update. there is different way of setting spark home path.